# Remove JSF completely from JBoss 6 or from Glassfish 3?

Tags: jsf-2, glassfish-3, tomcat7, jboss6.x, mojarra

I have a JSF Mojarra 2.0.3 app that was developed entirely on Tomcat 7 where it works superbly.  I need to deploy this application on JBoss or on Glassfish and the application runs but in some parts behaves strangely.  On both JBoss 6 and on Glassfish 3 this exact same bizarre behavior occurs.

I believe this happens for a number of reasons:

1) These app servers have their own version of Mojarra JSF bundled within them and these are being used in lieu of the Mojarra 2.0.3 I have in the applications web_inf/lib folder.

2) I am using a third party rich control toolkit that is probably behaving strangely because it expects this specific version of Mojarra (2.0.3 to be exact).

Bottom line is, I am floundering in every attempt to surgically remove JSF from one of these app servers because I strongly suspect this is the reason why these app servers behave differently from Tomcat, which does not have JSF joined at the hip.

Due to client prejudices and inhouse expertise, JBoss is required to host on production so using Tomcat in production is not an option.

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure where the libs are in JBoss(simple Google might tell you) but in Glassfish you'll just want to replace the JSF 2.0 jars.  They are located in .

install directory\glassfish\modules

Just replace the jsf-api and jsf-impl with the ones you used in the Tomcat version.  Then you'll be on the same page.